# Nginx 502 Bad Request [React, Spring Boot Auth service, Spring Boot resource service]

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

**Hello everyone,**

i´ve been trying for the past 4 days to make my containers communicate with each other but sadly it does not work.

I am able to access my website over memorial-hub.de but when ever i try my login POST request or the Register POST request triggered over my UI, im getting an 502 Bad Request exception.

[image]

I have checked following points:

- containers run on the same docker network
- my nginx container can ping my backend container
- checked nginx config within the container
- checked container network manually if they belong to the same, yes they do

here are my docker container running:
[image]

here is my nginx pinging my other containers
[image]

my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name memorial-hub.de;


    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

    location /api/v1/auth {
        proxy_pass http://authentication-service;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://service;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

my docker-compose (Keep in my that my nginx dockerfile is getting created in my frontend)

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  # Memorial Frontend aka. nginx, FE is build and nginx is used to serve the static files
  frontend:
    stdin_open: true
    image: memorial-client
    container_name: memorial-client-c
    build:
      context: ./memorial-frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/certificates:/etc/nginx/certificates
    networks:
      - frontend

  # Postgres database
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    container_name: psql-db-c
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: rsmt_admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./memorial-backend/src/main/resources/database/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/service-schema.sql:ro
      - ./AuthenticationProviderBE/src/main/resources/database/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ap-schema.sql:ro
    networks:
      - backend

  # Memorial Backend
  service:
    container_name: memorial-service-c
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    build:
      context: ./memorial-backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "7002:7002"
    environment:
      URS_DATABASE_URL: r2dbc:postgresql://*****:5432/memorial
      URS_DATABASE_USERNAME: rsmt_admin
      URS_DATABASE_PASSWORD: admin
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend

  #Authentication Service
  authentication-service:
    container_name: authentication-service-c
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    build:
      context: ./AuthenticationProviderBE
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "7001:7001"
    environment:
      URS_DATABASE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://*****:5432/ap
      URS_DATABASE_USERNAME: rsmt_admin
      URS_DATABASE_PASSWORD: admin
    networks:
      - backend
      - frontend
networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

Here is my Frontend/Nginx Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:20 AS builder

# Set the working directory to /client inside the container where the UI will be located at
# as if we would use "cd" in linux, if the folder does not exist, it will create the folder under the given path
WORKDIR /usr/src/client

# Copy app files to workdir inside the docker container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies (npm ci makes sure the exact versions in the lockfile gets installed)
RUN npm ci

# Copy all of the project files into the docker container
COPY . .

# RUN the build after installing dependencies and the "COPY" of the whole source code
RUN npm run build

##########################
# Use the official Nginx base image with Alpine Linux as the base image for the final production container.
# Nginx will be used to serve the static files generated by the React app.
FROM nginx:alpine

# Set the working directory inside the container to /usr/share/nginx/html, where Nginx serves the static content.
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file that comes with the image.
# We will replace it with our custom configuration file.
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy the custom Nginx configuration file from the host (your machine) to the container.
# This configuration file will be used by Nginx to serve the React app and handle incoming requests.
COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Remove all the existing files in the /usr/share/nginx/html directory to clear any default content that Nginx might have placed there.
RUN rm -rf ./*

# // TODO -> Refactor
# Test giving access to all users
# Since nginx is currently accesing the containers with "root" it still not have enough rights, which means we have to
# reassign the rights to the nginx user (currently Root) giving all possible rights
RUN chmod -R a+rx .

# Copy the production build files of the React app (generated in the previous build stage) from the "builder" stage into the /usr/share/nginx/html directory.
# This makes the built React app available to Nginx for serving.
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/client/dist .

USER nobody

# Set the default command that will run when the container starts.
# This command starts Nginx in the foreground to serve the React app and keeps the container running.
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, 502 Bad Gateway from NGINX means something is wrong with the upstream server.

Make sure the HTTP server http://authentication-service is reachable from the nginx and returns proper HTTP responses.

If I see it correctly your authentication-service runs on the port 7001, so the error probably lies in the nginx reverse proxy config. Make sure to set the correct port in there.

```
 server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name memorial-hub.de;


    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;
    }

    location /api/v1/auth {
        proxy_pass http://authentication-service:7001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://service:7002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

Also, just a note, there is no reason to run the server on these strange ports. Using docker encapsulates the network of each container if you are not using networkmode host, it is fine to just use the HTTP default port 80 for all webservers.

Comment: Added Ports as recommendet + i did setup in my backend services to use a specific PORT in my application.yaml which obviously i didnt redirect to within the docker container.